# Web part page and web part zone capatibility

Tags: 2010, web-part-zone

I deleted a webpart zone and added a table in it's place w/ 6 cells.  I added a table with 2 rows and 6 cells in its place and put a webpart zone in each cell.  If I don't put something in the last left cell content placed in the last right cell move into the last left cells position screwing up my page layout.

My purpose for this is to consume only selected webpart into easytabs by segregating those webparts in own zone.

Anyone know how to fix this?  Is it possible to create a webpart page with just divs and somehow add webpart zone to each div if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider re-writing your question as it's a bit confusing.

> Is it possible to create a webpart page with just divs and somehow add webpart zone to each div if so how?

Yes, edit the page in SharePoint Designer and add the web part zones in the DIVs you as need.